# Parameter Name must Match some Pattern

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

`public AbstractDomain getById(final Long lngARL_AUDIT_TRAIL_ID) {`   <---

Here in this section and I am getting this error:

```
Name lngARL_AUDIT_TRAIL_ID must match pattern ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

I don't know what to do and how to avoid it.

Need some solution.

Comment: This is why I would add a [custom message](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Custom_messages) to naming convention rules. It would have been much clearer if the message had been something like `Parameter name must start with a lowercase letter and consist only of letters and digits.`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `_` character in method parameter names. [Java code conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) say that you should try to avoid underscores in method or variable name whenever it is possible.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: But this *is* the answer. The regex does not allow underscores, and that is so because of the code conventions.

Comment: See also the [Google Java Style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.6-parameter-names) for parameter names.